# JQUERY - Page refresh at Window width of 1439px

Tags: jquery, resize, refresh

I'm trying to get the page to refresh when the window width crosses between 1439px. I know it's not good practice to do this, but I need to activate a plugin when the screen becomes smaller than 1439px. I've had a look around and have got a couple of instances to work, however the refresh just loops indefinitely.

Anyone know how to force the page to refresh at exactly 1439px and run once only?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that you really need to refresh the page? What plugin are you activating?

Comment: I'm building a responsive website which has logos running across the width of the footer. Obviously when the screen res gets smaller, theres not going to be enough room so I want to activate the plugin, jScrollpane at 1439px.

Comment: So you don't need to refresh the page after all! I'll post an answer shortly.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the best choice is append one parameter to the URL to don't reload the plugin. Something like this:

```
function getURLParameter(name) {
    return decodeURI(
        (RegExp(name + '=' + '(.+?)(&|$)').exec(location.search)||[,null])[1]
    );
}

if($(window).width() === 1439 && !getURLParameter(noReload))
      window.location.href = window.location.href + "?noReload=1&loadPlugin=1";
```

After that, you need to check if exists the param loadPlugin and load the plugin

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to refresh the page at all.

```
$(window).load(function(){
    var scrollPaneDone = false,
        testScrollPane = function(){
            if(scrollPaneDone || $(window).width() > 1439) return;
            $('#someElement').jScrollPane();
            scrollPaneDone = true;
        };
    $(window).bind('resize', testScrollPane);
    testScrollPane();
});
```

Explanation:

First, we define a variable scrollPaneDone, which will store whether or not we have already initialized the jScrollPane plugin. (So we don't initialize it twice)

Then, we define a function that checks if we have already initialized the scrollpane or if the window width is larger than 1439, the function will return and do nothing. Otherwise, we'll initialize the jScrollPane plugin and set our variable scrollPaneDone to true.

Then, we bind this function to the window resize event. And then call the function once, just in case the window is already less than 1439px it will activate the jScrollPane plugin on page load.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply, this works in part... It initialises the jScrollPane when you reduce the screen width to below 1439px, but it doesn't remove it again once increased. Any ideas?

Comment: Instead of doing that, I would suggest looking into jScrollPane's reinitialize function. http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/api.html#reinitialise which you can call any time the page is refreshed. You can bind this function to be called any time the page is resized and if the content has enough room, the scrollbars will disappear. This is a much cleaner solution.